# Integrating OOS(Office Online Server) with .NET web applications

Tags: .net, office365, ms-office

I would like to build some sort of API for my Office Online Server Farm, so I could call the opening and editing of documents from within a web application.

I want the web application to be separated from MS products so my intentions are not to use SharePoint or Exchange in order to work with the OOS.

Is there a way to mimic the process that SharePoint and Exchange use to work with Office Online, in such a way it could be used within other web applications? Any idea would suffice.

Comment: I'm also looking for a similar solution.  We'd like our clients to be able to open documents and collaborate on them in the course approving them, then releasing them.  We'd like to provide that using Office Online Server from a window within our software (using WOPI protocol, it appears).  So we'd need the software to be able to specify the document, open it in the Office Online Server window/iframe and allow the collaboration to take place there.   @rocky (user:1332034) is the person that seems most likely to be able to answer these questions.